# Why is this SQL query not returning the correct rows?

Tags: php, mysql

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to return rows that have a `NULL` or `0` value in a column where a `TIMESTAMP` column is before or equal to the current time.

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `drafts` 
WHERE `leagueid`="vH8j5R0nlsBYhOUm" 
AND (`pick_uid`=NULL OR `pick_uid`='0')
AND `deadline` >= "2015-9-28 13:43:00";
```

NB: I'm using a string value for `deadline` instead of `NOW()` because the users have different timezones and so I create a timestamp using the PHP function `gmdate` to ensure the request is in UTC.

**Table Screenshot**
[image: Table Screenshot]

**What I'm expecting returned from this query**

All rows with `id<=709`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably due to using `=` with `NULL`, try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM `drafts` 
WHERE `leagueid`="vH8j5R0nlsBYhOUm" 
    AND (`pick_uid` IS NULL OR `pick_uid`='0')
    AND `deadline` >= "2015-9-28 13:43";
```

Comment: Yes this works! Thank you. Why does SQL not recognise `=` for NULL values?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan, arithmetic operators are not allowed with `NULL`, for details see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>.

We will have to use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators instead.